# How to debug JDK source

Tags: eclipse, debugging, java

I have one very tricky issue that I am not able to sort out right away. I have to debug JDK source to see whether I can move further. The standard JDK library does not come with Debug symbol included.

Can anyone tell me where I can download the JDK debug version? I am using eclipse and debug remotely, JDK 1.5 or 1.6 are both fine for my case. If not, I probably have to follow a googled guide to re-compile the `rt.jar`.

To be more clear, I want a JDK distribution with debug enabled. Where can I download it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check on debug symbol status with Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203321/how-can-i-check-on-debug-symbol-status-with-eclipse).  The short answer is use a JDK rather than a JRE.  (The linked question's title is misleading.  Read the actual question and answers.)

Comment: Same problem here and I was not able able to compile the whole jdk (8) sources as described in the "google guide" without errors.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is) for an excelent guide on how to compile the JDK sources with debug.  I just followed it today (on a linux box) and it worked perfectly.  (Would have worked perfectly the first time, if I hadn't decided to try 'improving' it.)  I actually did recompile the entire source, and it appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you just to compile the classes you need with debug information and put your version of `*class` files of JDK to bootstrap classpath. Configure your IDE with attached sources (src.zip). This should work.

I hope you do not really need whole JDK, just selected classes.

Comment: you are missing the question... how to get the debug version of .class'es

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255474/debug-jdk-source-cant-watch-variable-what-it-is) for how to get a debug version of the java libraries.