# Why debugging jdk libraries in eclipse, I can't see local variables values?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The problem is that while debugging java library classes, e.g. HashSet functions I cant see local variables. On `variables` tab I can only see function parameters and *this*'s fields. When I'm trying to add local variable to `watch`, eclipse says: "errors during evaluation".

So my question is why does this happens? And how can I see those local variables values?

Answer (score 5):

Long story short, JDK distributions aren't compiled with debug information.

Check the answers to these questions:

- [How to debug JDK source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498282/how-to-debug-jdk-source)
- [How can I check on debug symbol status with Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203321/how-can-i-check-on-debug-symbol-status-with-eclipse)