# Unable to find resource using getResource method

Tags: java

There is a resource (PNG image) inside the folder /resources/images/.

However, when I execute the following code I get an error, because the URL is null.

```
URL url = Test.class.getResource("/resources/images/icone.png");
```

However, when I debug the code it seems that the parameter "/resources/images/icone.png" is not passed at all, because Eclipse says it is null, as you can see on the image below:

[image: parameter is null]

I've searched a lot through the internet and I can't find an answer. Please, anyone has an advice?

Comment: Where is your resources folder relative to your class files?

Comment: Did you try `getResource("/images/icone.png")`?

Comment: getResource() doesn't load from folders. It loads from the classpath. You need to tell us what your classpath is, and where in the classpath the image is located.

Comment: To add to what @JBNizet said, you would have to put the image in your drawable folder then call `getResource(R.drawable.YourImage);`

Comment: The `name` variable isn't null. It just appears this way, because, well, [because the way Eclipse works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451558/why-debugging-jdk-libraries-in-eclipse-i-cant-see-local-variables-values). I'd advice you to use a [better IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels the project structure is as you can see below:

- project
    - src (source folder) - classes are here
    - test (source folder)
    - resources (not a source folder)
       - images (images are here)

As you can see, my classpath is the src folder + test folder + maven libraries

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the resources folder wasn't a source folder.

To fix it I added the resources folder as a source folder and changed the image path to images/icone.png.