# How to know from .class file if debug metadata is included?

Tags: java

How can I tell if compiled java classes have debug metadata included?

Optional:

It would be nice only if I could see if debug metadata is lines, vars or source or combination of some of them.

Found nice tool for viewing .class files (http://www.codexterity.com/classexp.htm) but that's where I am stuck not sure where to look. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, there is bytecode in the class file that have debug information.

If you run `javap -v` on the class file, you will see the debug information that is available. It is worth compiling a simple test class with different `-g` option settings and looking at the results with `javap`.

See [Check if Java bytecode contains debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145826/check-if-java-bytecode-contains-debug-symbols) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Normally only line numbers are included but you can use '-g' option this option generates all debugging information, including local variables.

Read about [Debug information in Java .class files](http://www.narendranaidu.com/2005/12/debug-information-in-java-class-files.html)

Comment: My question is more about reverse-process, how can I from .class file know if it was compiled with -g or maybe -g:none (no debug info) option? Thanks for the link.