# What does the jlink command line parameter --strip-debug mean?

Tags: java, jlink

Which effect hat the `jlink` command line parameter `--strip-debug`?

In the documentation at [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm) you can read:

> Strips debug information from the output image

But what does this meas? Which type of debug information will be removed? I can think of line numbers of stacktraces. Does it mean that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its more in order to get rid of the *debug symbols* which shall include the line numbers (yes), local variable details and possibly the comments in the bytecode generated as well, for e.g. :

```
public com.some.pack.ReferenceVariableSample();
  Code:
    0: aload_0
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4: return
```

Haven't given it a try myself though, but you can [Check if Java bytecode contains debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145826/check-if-java-bytecode-contains-debug-symbols) and compare it with a runtime image created using `--strip-debug` via [jlink](/questions/tagged/jlink).